# How can a Windows filter driver send IOCTL_HID_SET_FEATURE request to hidusb/HID minidriver?

Tags: windows, driver, hid, ioctl, kmdf

We created two drivers, My_FilterDriver & My_HIDMiniDriver. To describe more details, please take a look the below screen of Device Manager.

[image]

At USB Input Device, by default it is installed hidclass, hidusb drivers. We replace hidusb with My_HIDMiniDriver which is a HID Minidriver.
A HID Minidriver is a minidriver of hidclass, it handles IOCTL_HID_SET_FEATURE requests. For more details refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/creating-umdf-hid-minidrivers.

At HID-compliant vendor-defined device, by default no driver is installed. We install My_FilterDriver which is a lower filter driver of null function driver.

The stack looks like:
My_FilterDriver -> hidclass -> hidusb or My_HIDMiniDriver

In My_FilterDriver, we tried to send request to local I/O target,

```
status = WdfIoTargetSendIoctlSynchronously(
    WdfDeviceGetIoTarget(devContext->Device),
    NULL,
    IOCTL_HID_SET_FEATURE,
    &inputDescriptor,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL);
```

The problem:
It returns 0xc0000061 (= STATUS_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD, A required privilege is not held by the client).

The question:
Can a filter driver send a SET_FEATURE request to the hidusb/HID minidriver? If it can, how should it do?

---

Test case 1:
If we call HidD_SetFeature in a user mode Application, My_HIDMiniDriver can receive the IOCTL_HID_SET_FEATURE request. So that we can check if the SET_FEATURE request is passing through hidusb or My_HIDMiniDriver.

Test case 2:
If we replace WdfIoTargetSendIoctlSynchronously with WdfIoTargetSendInternalIoctlSynchronously, the internal function returns success, but HID minidriver does not receive the IOCTL_HID_SET_FEATURE request.

Test case 3:
If we replace the IoctlCode with IOCTL_HID_GET_COLLECTION_INFORMATION or IOCTL_HID_GET_COLLECTION_DESCRIPTOR, WdfIoTargetSendIoctlSynchronously() return success and we can get HID_COLLECTION_INFORMATION and PreparsedData. So that we can make sure the local I/O target is the exact device that installed hidclass/hidusb.